# Enable dark-mode by preference or an app-set property

Tags: css, themes

I'm building a webapp that has a dark and light theme. I want to serve either based on the OS/browser preference of the user. However, in my webapp their will be a setting to override that. So let's say a user has dark-mode preference according to his OS/browser, then he can still choose to use light-mode. My initial idea was to set a data-attribute on the body-tag with JS when a user chooses this mode.

I'm using CSS variables for my colour schemes. Now, the question is: can I combine this in one sort-of query, without writing duplicate code? My current implementation with duplicate code is, simplified, as follows:

```
:root {
  --background: white;
  --text: black;
}

body[data-theme='dark'] {
  --background: black;
  --text: white;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body:not[data-theme='light'] {
    --background: black;
    --text: white;
  }
}
```

So:

- Default I serve a light-theme
- When your browser/OS says you prefer dark, you get dark
- When you pick light or dark in the webapp, it will override your browser/OS preference

The problem here is of course that I have duplicate code to set the dark theme variables. Is there any CSS-approach to fix this (so no SCSS/Less etc.)?